# Angularjs: javascript outside of template not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, templates, filter

:) I have a input in the body of my index.html file Which acts like a static header to my templates. The only problem is that i have the filter in my template like so:

`<!-- Home Template -->
    <script id="home.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <ion-view title="plz help">
        <ion-content>
          <div class="list" id="list" ng-repeat="phone in phones | filter:query">
            ...
          </div>
        </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
    </script>`

So that makes it "2 separate files" (they are both inside index.html). This makes it so that i can't for example "clear the filter" from a button in my header that's outside of the template.

Is there any way I can "include" the different "files" in each other so that i can execute JavaScript in in both "files"?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a nested scope. Because `query` live in root scope, is visible from scope of your controller. You have exemple [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/5eQNCz)

But, sometimes there is a problem that variable from root or parent scope is not visible in nested scope if previously is not defined in main controller. Also, you can use `$rootScope` service to easier access.

Hope to I clarified a little.

Comment: Thank you! you make it look so easy! :L Thanks for an obvious and great answer mate!! :)